Why is the subject in the accusative case in this sentence?
Here the subject (I) appears to be in the accusative or genitive case.
Меня не было здесь вчера - is that caused by the negative expression please?

Were any of the answers to the questions you asked before useful to you? If yes, please mark them as accepted. You can do that by clicking the checkmark icon to the left of the answer, right below the number of votes. Thank you!

Меня is not the subject here. The literal translation would be something like "There wasn't [any] of me here yesterday".
